# Apache ищет .htaccess не в той директории

Tags: apache

Настраиваю локальный сервер.

Собственно проблема описана в заголовке.

Настройка хоста:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName em


DocumentRoot /home/devel/web/www/em
ErrorLog /home/devel/web/log/em/error.log
</VirtualHost>
```

В логах хоста:

> [Fri Aug 23 14:22:21 2013] [crit] [client 127.0.0.1] (13)Permission denied: /home/devel/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable

Comment: Спасибо. Вот это я как раз и не проверил. Теперь заработало.

Answer (score 2):

`/home/devel/` доступна на запуск хотя-бы апачу ?